# Problems when using Access Point

Tags: 11.10, wireless, networking

I recently bought a [Sitecom Wireless Network Access Point 300N WL-331](http://www.sitecom.com/wireless-network-access-point-300n/p/715). It's very easy to install. I tested the connection by connecting from 2 different laptops running Windows 7 (everything went fine) , then I tried it with 2 android devices (again everything went fine).

Now it was time to try using the AP from Ubuntu 11.10. (One of the laptops run on dualboot). Since I boot into Ubuntu 95% of the time, it's essential that this works.

I tried connecting, it worked perfectly. All pages load fast, I did a speed test and I get 47mbps download (my ISP provides 50mbps so that's good)

Once I added some security to the AP (WEP key) some problems came up on my Ubuntu machine:

- When I connect the first page displays fast (google.com) but it keeps on loading
- After that when I try loading ANY other page it takes ages... :(

If I reset the AP and leave it unprotected, everything is nice and fast. I also tried adding a WPA protection but the same problem keeps occurring.

**EDIT:** Wireless Card: Intel Link 5100

**Anyone got an idea?**

PS: After adding a protection, I tried again on the Windows machines + android devices and they run like they were running before so I'm guessing it's an Ubuntu issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: plz add more information about your wireless card.

Comment: Wireless card information added ;)

Answer (score 2):

Edit the file (or create) `/etc/modprobe.d/options.conf`, add the line

```
options iwlagn 11n_disable=1
```

or

```
options iwlagn 11n_disable50=1
```

Try each and see which works for you.

Reboot for testing on each line you are testing

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Thanks, will try this when I get home and keep you updated.

Comment: perfect ;) anything, drop a comment.

Comment: I just created the file as instructed and rebooted and now I don't even have the option to connect to a wireless network. Seems like my wireless has dissapeared. Any other ideas? Thx alot already :-) EDIT: I just left the "options iwlagn 11n_disable=1" in it and now it seems to be working ;).

EDIT2: I just did a speedtest and I'm only getting half of my speed I should be getting. I tested it on my Windows OS and it was double the speed I have now on my Ubuntu machine. Any idea?

Comment: This disables N rate speeds in your wireless card so its normal that you do not have the same speeds as using the windows drivers, I think this is reported somewhere as a `network-manager` problem one of the solutions removes `network-manager` and installs `wicd` instead, might work for you but can also break (believe not but you never know) your system a bit. Drop a comment if you are interested in trying this.

Comment: Sure I'm definitely interested in trying it out, any guidance? Already upvoted btw

Comment: Just tried installing wicd and removing network-manager. Now I am not able to see my AP. (Thus not even able to connect) Any help? Ill send you a couple of (Belgian) beers if we can get this up and running the way it should :D

Comment: I am sure you can add one by hand, it should be simple, open `wicd` and add a wireless interface with dhcp connection (im testing this now if I find it weird ill let you know).

Comment: Hmm weird, I (temporarily) moved the options.conf file, re-installed network-manager alongside wicd, and now I'm able to see my AP. I'm connected to it and everything seems to be working altough a minute ago I had the same issue. Reconnected and now it's working again. (Edit: Even that the options.conf file is removed I still only get the 25mbps of the 47mbps I'm getting in Windows)